# how to apply a orderBy filter based on the input filed dynamically requested by user?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have model like:

Which is iterated:

I also have a text box:

originally, the list will display ALL of the comments ,in the order as in the modal.

What I want is for the user to type into the text box and have the list change based on what he types.
EXAMPLE: user types nothing -> the comments displayed should be in same order
                 user types: date   -> the comments displayed should be in the date order or in the rating order or in the author name order
          Here how to apply orderBy filter

Can someone please provide me with some sample code (JQuery and Javascript) to aid me in this endeavor?

Comment: so when the user types rating on the textbox then it will be sorted by rating? Am I understanding your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your textbox available as a $scope property then you can use that to orderBy your list by using the built in angular orderBy filter. So if you type rating the list will be ordered by rating.

**Controller**

```
function sampleCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    rating: 2,
    author: "author 3"
  }, {
    rating: 1,
    author: "author 5"
  }, {
    rating: 6,
    author: "author 2"
  }];
}
```

**View**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    <div ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: filterText">
      {{item.rating}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0aeavgfa/)